# How to find href link from multiple browser tabs

Tags: selenium

I wrote this code to fetch the href link of images in webpage. However i found this way to do this, But Unable to find link in loop. I want that when new tab open href link of that tabs get print in shell. And the urls link are multiple.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import urllib
import urllib.request
import time
import os


#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\umesh.kumar\Downloads\Codes\chromedriver.exe")
username = "ABCD.kumar"
password = "X0XX"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://propadmin.99acres.com/propadmin/index.htm")
urls = ["https://propadmin.99acres.com/do/seller/ProcessSellerForms/getDeletedPhotos?prop_id=A18056415", "https://propadmin.xxxxxxx.com/do/seller/ProcessSellerForms/getDeletedPhotos?prop_id=A56063622"]
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()

for posts in range(len(urls)):
    print(posts)
    driver.get(urls[posts])    
    if(posts!=len(urls)-1):
       driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
       chwd = driver.window_handles
       driver.switch_to.window(chwd[-1])

elems = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
for elem in elems:
        href = elem.get_attribute('href')
        if href is not None:
            print(href)
```

Comment: So you want to print the page url? when you do `driver.switch_to.window(chwd[-1])`?

Comment: Yes. i am able to do that on one Url but when I had entered multiple url in urls list its only how that last urls href link only but i want on multiple urls from url list

Comment: You simply need to indent after elems so that it goes inside the switch.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan- Please specify how can indent it.